# send data value with email in joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, email, joomla, send, calculator

I just created a module calculator for joomla 2.5. I want to send the information entered by users to an email address

```
<div class="formRow">
<label id="jform_varListCarburant-lbl" for="jform_varListCarburant" class=""><?php echo JText::_("MOD_MODULESCASCODEVIS_EN_LIGNE_VARLISTCARBURANT"); ?></label>
<select id="jform_varListCarburant" name="jform[varListCarburant]" class="">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" <?php if($varListCarburant=="0") echo "selected=\"selected\"" ?>><?php echo JText::_("Choisir"); ?></option>
    <option <?php if($varListCarburant=="1") echo "selected=\"selected\"" ?> value="1">Essence</option>
    <option <?php if($varListCarburant=="2") echo "selected=\"selected\"" ?> value="2">Diesel</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Variables for calculator :

```
$varListCarburant = isset($form["varListCarburant"]) ? $form["varListCarburant"] : "";

$varListCarburant = preg_replace('/[^0-9.\-]/', '', str_replace(',', '.', $varListCarburant));

$varListPuissance = isset($form["varListPuissance"]) ? $form["varListPuissance"] : "";

$varListPuissance = preg_replace('/[^0-9.\-]/', '', str_replace(',', '.', $varListPuissance));

$varListUsage = isset($form["varListUsage"]) ? $form["varListUsage"] : "";

$varListUsage = preg_replace('/[^0-9.\-]/', '', str_replace(',', '.', $varListUsage));

$varListEtatvoiture = isset($form["varListEtatvoiture"]) ? $form["varListEtatvoiture"] : "";

$varListEtatvoiture = preg_replace('/[^0-9.\-]/', '', str_replace(',', '.', $varListEtatvoiture));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for sharing this wonderful idea .. and while this post is being down voted and probably closed, go have a read at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) ..

Comment: read this, please: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16278454/632407

Answer (score 0):

```
 $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
        $mailer->setSender(array($fromemail, 'Your mail text'));
        $mailer->addRecipient($toemail);
        $mailer->setSubject($subject);
        $mailer->setBody($body);
        $mailer->IsHTML(false);
        $mailer->Send();
```